# Determine if two types appear within a timeframe, after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where each row represents an event, with a date and a few pieces of information about the event. I would like to know whether, after grouping by one column (`a`), multiple types of another column (`b`) appear within a short timeframe (say, `+/- 60 days`), and keep rows where this is the case.

With a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
     a      b          date
    foo    blue     2018-02-17
    foo    blue     2018-02-22
    foo    red      2018-04-28
    foo    blue     2018-04-29
    foo    blue     2018-05-02
    foo    red      2018-08-01
    bar    yellow   2018-01-25
    bar    red      2018-04-07
    bar    yellow   2018-07-11
    bar    yellow   2018-07-14
    baz    red      2018-03-11
    baz    blue     2018-04-14
    baz    red      2018-07-05
    baz    blue     2018-10-01
```

I would like to select the following rows:

```
     a      b          date
    foo    red      2018-04-28
    foo    blue     2018-04-29
    foo    blue     2018-05-02
    baz    red      2018-03-11
    baz    blue     2018-04-14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning with the example you pasted in:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','date'],
                  data=[['foo','blue','2018-02-17'],['foo','blue','2018-02-22'],['foo','red','2018-04-28'],['foo','blue','2018-04-29'],['foo','blue','2018-05-02'],
                        ['foo','red','2018-08-01'],['bar','yellow','2018-01-25'],['bar','red','2018-04-07'],['bar','yellow','2018-07-11'],
                        ['bar','yellow','2018-07-14'],['baz','red','2018-03-11'],['baz','blue','2018-04-14'],['baz','red','2018-07-05'],['baz','blue','2018-10-01']])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df

    a    b       date
0   foo  blue    2018-02-17
1   foo  blue    2018-02-22
2   foo  red     2018-04-28
3   foo  blue    2018-04-29
4   foo  blue    2018-05-02
5   foo  red     2018-08-01
6   bar  yellow  2018-01-25
7   bar  red     2018-04-07
8   bar  yellow  2018-07-11
9   bar  yellow  2018-07-14
10  baz  red     2018-03-11
11  baz  blue    2018-04-14
12  baz  red     2018-07-05
13  baz  blue    2018-10-01
```

I determined what subset of rows in the df I'd need to search over, given timeframe size. I use the same timeframe of 60 days (+/- 30 days) as in your example.

```
win_sz = pd.Timedelta(days=60)
start = df['date'].min() + win_sz/2
end = df['date'].max() - win_sz/2
to_search_over = df[(df['date'] > start) & (df['date'] <= end)]['date']
```

Next,

- For each row in the `to_search_over` list above, I grab a subset of the df that has all rows with dates that fall inside the date range that corresponds to our date window size (60 days in this case).
- For this window, I use `groupby()` and `nunique()` to check if a given element in column `a` has more than one value in column `b` associated with it.
- Finally, I add any indices of rows that satisfy this criteria to a list (`res`).

```
res = []

for d in to_search_over:
    mask = (df['date'] > d-(win_sz/2)) & (df['date'] <= d+(win_sz/2))
    window = df.loc[mask]
    a = window.groupby('a')['b'].nunique()
    a = a[a>1].index.values
    if a.any():
        res += list(window[window['a'].isin(a)].index)
```

I convert this list of indices to a set, and then back to a list in order to keep only unique row values. I can then slice the df to return all rows that meet our criteria:

```
df.iloc[list(set(res))]

    a    b      date
2   foo  red    2018-04-28
3   foo  blue   2018-04-29
4   foo  blue   2018-05-02
10  baz  red    2018-03-11
11  baz  blue   2018-04-14
```

I'd be excited to see if anyone has a more elegant way of accomplishing this (an approach that doesn't entail explicitly iterating row-by-row over a subset of the df's rows). I spent a while trying to find an approach that used `pd.rolling`, but to no avail.